# Is it possible to assign a bevel curve to an armature like an object?

Tags: rigging, armature, bezier-curves, bevel

I couldn't find an answer for this, so I'm asking here:

I have some bevel curves on my player model and I've used automatic weights to rig the character except the bevel curves that I've used for the hair aren't following. Is there a setting or trick to make the bevel curves follow the armature?

Also due to this model being used for an upcoming game, I cannot upload or share it sorry :(

Answer (score 1):

If you're gonna export the model, the best way is to select the curve and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> convert it into a mesh.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question at all. I need to know how to assign a bevel curve to an armature so that it follows the armature, since it's the hair and I can't have it floating in the air.

Comment: If the hair is a mesh, it can be weighted to a bone and animated as anything else; if it's a curve you can parent it to a bone (select the curve, then the armature, go to pose mode, select the bone, Ctrl P bone). You can also animate curves with the AnimAll addon. In every of thoose last cases you'll have problems while exporting.